Convert a PNG file to a line layer in QGIS
I have a map in PNG-format that looks like this:

I have imported it into QGIS as a raster. I want to create a line layer as a network based on the blue and pink lines. Is there a way to create a line vector layer from this map without digitizing it by hand?

source data looks like it would be in vector format - is this data source online? - you need to georeference the png first then vectorise the colours out of the image.

No the source data is not online. I just have this PNG file.
How can I vectorize the colours from the grid?

Probably easier to find the data as a vector layer, then split it manually based on the raster layer.

When your png is georeferenced than you can go this way:
select the png-file in the layer bar.
In the main menu select
Raster - Conversion - Vectorise (raster to vector).
In the new window, select the png file again and start the process.
I just tried in gimp menu: tools - selection tools - select by colour, then I remove all colours except blue and violet

with this the raster to vector conversion in QGIS works not too bad.

This does not work because the blue is present in different shades. I then get a colourful mosaic

Can you pre-process it in something like GIMP to convert the dark blue and pink to black, and all other colours to white?

Yes, that works! But how do I get the line vector layer from the raster/PNG? I tried r.thin and than r.to.vect, but that doesn't work.
